# vscode for a Go project with some wasm packages and some arm64 packages

Tags: go, vscode-extensions, webassembly

I am developing a Go application in VSCode. Some of the packages in my project are compiled to wasm and run in the browser, while others compile to linux executables and run on the backend.

Crucially, there are also some packages that are imported on both sides -- for example the structs that I pass between frontend and backend.

In VSCode, using the Go extension, it seems that I can choose either GOARCH=wasm or GOARCH=arm64. If I choose GOARCH=arm64, then I get compile errors in files that import "syscall/js", saying that all files in this package are excluded by build constraints (which makes perfect sense). However, if I switch vscode to GOARCH=wasm then I get compile errors in files that import packages with no wasm implementation -- for example, "golang.org/x/sys/unix" -- which also makes perfect sense, but it leaves me having to either constantly switch my GOARCH/GOOS settings in vscode, or else work without autocomplete in a large fraction of my source files.

Is there any way I can get the best of both worlds? Can I tell vscode to use GOARCH=wasm in certain packages, and GOARCH=arm64 in other packages, all within a single project?

I realize that I could split my code into totally separate projects and open them in different vscode windows, but I don't want to do that because there is actually a lot of code shared between the frontend (wasm) and backend (arm64) parts -- that's the motivation for using Go on both frontend and backend in the first place.

Comment: Currently, the Go language server does not support build tags very well. See the discussions in this issue: [x/tools/gopls: improve handling for build tags #29202](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29202).